# Commit фрагмента после смены ориентации экрана

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте! У меня есть `FragmentActivity`, который использует `layout` и `layout-land` разметку. После смены ориентации устройства и последующего `commit()` фрагмента я получаю ошибку, которую никак не могу исправить:

```
 «IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState»
```

Я не могу заблокировать смену ориентации экрана, т.к. нужно менять разметку на land при повороте экрана.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, как исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Приведите код метода onSaveInstanceState а также onPause

Comment: Просто переопределяю эти 2 метода с super.  Всё-таки нужно копать в сторону этих методов?

Comment: Пожалуй да. Судя вот по этой ссылке (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10261438/3212712) проблема может быть из-за commit транзакции после onPause() активити. Засим нам надо ваш код увидеть, а именно в каком методе жиз. цикла активити вы вызываете commit

Comment: Понял! Проблема в том, что commit вызывался после onPause() и последующим onResume. Активити пересоздалось из-за автоповорота, а во фрагменте ссылка на getActivity() осталась старая и по ней он и пытался сделать commit.